# I have a carousel which is displaying 4 images at a time in desktop. I want only one image should display at a time in Mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel which is displaying 4 images at a time in the desktop. I want only one image should display at a time in Mobile view. How to make this responsive?
Can anyone tell me how to make this using only html and css codes?

Comment: What did you try ? First post your code example and then ask question please.

Answer (score 1):

try media queries, specifying the width range for mobile device.
i think you can refer to this `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries`